# Imgur images take too long to download

Tags: networking, router, internet, isp, imgur

## Short description

Recently my ISP changed my modem/router and I'm experiencing now slow downloads in some sites (imgur.com, tenor.com for example), that worked fine with my previous router. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my router's configuration or it's an ISP problem, and they would not be of any help providing me information.

## More Information

I'm not sure what kind of information is useful in these situations, but these are some things that I noticed.

My internet connection plan is 25 Mbps download and 3 Mbps upload, and I verified this through fast.com and speedtest.net though sometimes it's slower, but generally it's high even when measured at the time when the aforementioned problem happens.

Ping is usually 10ms (stackoverflow.com) but for i.imgur.com it's ~ 160ms

```
> ping i.imgur.com

Pinging prod.imgur.map.fastlylb.net [151.101.204.193] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 151.101.204.193: bytes=32 time=170ms TTL=56
Reply from 151.101.204.193: bytes=32 time=150ms TTL=56
Reply from 151.101.204.193: bytes=32 time=157ms TTL=56
Reply from 151.101.204.193: bytes=32 time=151ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 151.101.204.193:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 150ms, Maximum = 170ms, Average = 157ms
```

---

```
> tracert i.imgur.com

Tracing route to prod.imgur.map.fastlylb.net [151.101.4.193]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5    26 ms    15 ms    16 ms  150-165-89-200.fibertel.com.ar [200.89.165.150]

  6    13 ms    12 ms    11 ms  149-165-89-200.fibertel.com.ar [200.89.165.149]

  7    12 ms    11 ms    12 ms  5-165-89-200.fibertel.com.ar [200.89.165.5]
  8    13 ms    15 ms    39 ms  250-165-89-200.fibertel.com.ar [200.89.165.250]

  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10   137 ms   135 ms   137 ms  ae1-300G.ar5.MIA1.gblx.net [67.17.94.249]
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12   138 ms   137 ms   136 ms  4.7.42.110
 13   136 ms   136 ms   135 ms  151.101.4.193

Trace complete.
```

---

I'm not sure what kind of method imgur uses to download images but I noticed that even small images takes too long to download.

Here's a Chrome "Network" panel screenshot:

[image]

I did also try using a VPN with same results.

### Edit

I moved my answer here since it was not the solution.
My ISP sent a technician to my home. He looked at the modem/router and said it was ok, and then reviewed the street box and said there was a problem there (he didn't give me too much detail and I'm not an expert) and that they'll be fixing it in the following days. Apparently there was too much signal noise which was causing a lot of packet loss. The next day I came home and noticed that the problem was gone. I verified that the ping and tracert values were still the same but I could navigate normally. After I couple of days the problem slowly come back, so I'll be reporting back to them.

## Other info

- Connection: Cable modem, Ethernet and Wi-Fi
- Router: Sagemcom F@ST 3686 AC
- ISP: Cablevision Fibertel (Buenos Aires, Argentina)
- Browser: Chrome 67.0.3396.99, Windows 7 64 bit
- DNS: 8.8.8.8
- Fast.com info: Latency(12 ms/Unloaded, 150 ms/Loaded), Upload: 2.8 Mbps, Settings: 20MB/10MB
- BufferBloat test: http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/36039227

Comment: That tracert shows clearly that the issue is on your ISPs network.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill. I guess the only thing I can do then is to complain with them, right? Should I close the question?

Comment: Not yet... What DNS server are you using? (Where approximately is the DNS server located?) Does the domain resolve to the same IP address if you try different DNS servers?

Comment: @grawity I'm using google dns. The domain resolves to the same IP using my ISP dns (200.42.4.204)

Comment: There are several strange things going on here. For one thing, you're being routed to Miami (I assume Imgur has servers in South-America), which suggests a DNS or routing error. However, 136ms return trip time is quite normal for that distance, and should not be a problem for small downloads. So there must be another issue; this could be a high error rate due to interference, but it could be something else. I suggest you run a bigger ping (for instance: ping -l 1400 -n 100 i.imgur.com) and post the summary.

Comment: Hi @Paul, thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately, I moved from that home some years ago so I won't be able to test it. I'm not sure what is normally done in these cases, should I delete the question?

Comment: Deleting is probably best, otherwise it will keep popping up (as it did for me)